# How to redirect to https on tomcat behind ELB

Tags: tomcat, ssl, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb

I have following setup on AWS

ELB (terminates SSL) -> nginx receives http on 80 and forwards to -> tomcat on 8080

But when i do a response.sendRedirect("/somepath") in my servlet then the browser is receiving it as 302 http://example.com/somepath

But I want the browser to get https://example.com/somepath, how do I achieve this in tomcat or nginx without setting up SSL on them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because of response.sendRedirect();

> SSL Offloading servers actually cause this problem of https URLs
>   getting converted into http URLs in case of sendRedirect. Let's try to
>   understand how it all happens. When an https URL reaches an
>   intermediate SSL Offloading server, the request is decoded (to offload
>   the decoding task which would have been done by the actual target
>   server otherwise) into an http request and the SSL Offloader now sends
>   that decoded http request to the actual target server (it may go
>   through few other intermediary servers for other purposes as well).
>   Now, the target server has no clue whether it was originally an https
>   request or not and it treats it as an http request only. This is the
>   reason why a servlet calling sendRedirect on the target server will
>   result into an http URL for the redirected resource (having a relative
>   URL)and the same http URL is sent back to the client browser.
>   Remember, no SSL Offloading server will come into picture for this URL
>   as it's an http request and not an https request. If the redirected
>   resource is an absolute https URL then also an intermediate SSL
>   Offloader may convert that https request into an http request before
>   it reaches to the client browser.

The solution to the problem is implementing a Filter and override sendRedirect in  HttpServletResponseWrapper.

Filter.

```
public class AbsoluteSendRedirectFilter implements Filter {
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { }
    public void destroy() { }
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
            ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //continue the request
        chain.doFilter(request, new SendRedirectOverloadedResponse(request, response));
    }
}
```

HttpServletResponseWrapper

```
public class SendRedirectOverloadedResponse extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

    private HttpServletRequest m_request;
    private String prefix = null;

    public SendRedirectOverloadedResponse(HttpServletRequest inRequest,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
        m_request = inRequest;
        prefix = getPrefix(inRequest);
    }

    public void sendRedirect(String location) throws IOException {
        String finalurl = null;
        if (isUrlAbsolute(location)) {
            finalurl = location;
        } else {
            finalurl = fixForScheme(prefix + location);
        }
        super.sendRedirect(finalurl);
    }

    public boolean isUrlAbsolute(String url) {
        return url.toLowerCase().startsWith("http");
    }

    public String fixForScheme(String url) {
        //alter the url here if you were to change the scheme return url;
    }

    public String getPrefix(HttpServletRequest request) {
        StringBuffer str = request.getRequestURL();
        String url = str.toString();
        String uri = request.getRequestURI();
        int offset = url.indexOf(uri);
        String prefix = url.substring(0,offset);
    }
}
```

Resources came from here:
http://www.hoitikwong.com/2013/03/the-mystery-case-of-https-becoming-http.html and
http://geekexplains.blogspot.in/2008/06/https-becoming-http-in-case-of.html

Comment: wow.. 12 hours of research/trials and I finally stumbled onto this. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try setting IS_SSL=ssl request header for all requests at LB level. nginx then pass response as with origin url with https