# Can a redirect to relative path be sent from Java Servlet API?

Tags: java, http, servlets, jetty

I would like to send relative redirect (to the original request domain & port) to the browser.

Like this:

```
Location: /app
```

But `Jetty` send automatically the full absolute path

```
Location:http://10.0.2.17:9080/app
```

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)) also mentions that the relative URL must be converted to the absolute URL by the servlet container.

Is it even possible to send a relative URL with redirect?

Comment: No. That would violate the http specs.

Comment: "An obsolete version of the HTTP 1.1 specifications (IETF RFC 2616) required a complete absolute URI for redirection.[2] The IETF HTTP working group found that the most popular web browsers tolerate the passing of a relative URL[3] and, consequently, the updated HTTP 1.1 specifications (IETF RFC 7231) relaxed the original constraint, allowing the use of relative URLs in Location headers.[4]

Comment: sadly java/servlet/spec was not updated.. or is it now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just manually set the redirect status and header. Replace `response.sendRedirect(url)` by

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
response.setHeader("Location", url);
```

Comment: note - this will only work if you configure your Jersey to not autoresolve your relative urls to absolute:
        
 
 
 
 environment.jersey().property(ServerProperties.LOCATION_HEADER_RELATIVE_URI_RESOLUTION_DISABLED, true);